# Chocolatey - Installation exists but command does not run

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I attempted to install Chocolatey and the command returned that the installation already existed, but when I ran `choco -?`, it returned an error that the command didn't exist.

[Image of Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBIN6.png)

Comment: Did you check if the path to choco.exe is in your PATH variable?

Comment: Unless you need to preserve something from the previous installation, manually remove directory `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey`, then try installing again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using @mklement0 's solution. I deleted `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey` and reinstalled chocolatey normally.